# How to solve this limit without L'Hopital? $\lim_{n\to \infty } (6^{1/n}+4^{1/n}-3^{1/n})^n$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I assume it would work since I think the three components exists in their own but I'm not really sure if it works like that but this is the method I tried, can anyone confirm that I didn't mess up?

$$A=\lim_{n\to \infty }  (6^{1/n}+4^{1/n}-3^{1/n})^n$$
$$\log (A)=\log (\lim_{n\to \infty }  (6^{1/n}+4^{1/n}-3^{1/n}))^n$$
$$\log (A)= n\cdot \log (\lim_{n\to \infty }  (6^{1/n}+4^{1/n}-3^{1/n}))$$

$$\log(A)= n\cdot \log( \lim_{n\to \infty }6^{1/n}+\lim_{n\to \infty } 4^{1/n}- \lim_{n\to \infty }3^{1/n}))$$

Is this allowed or am I messing up somewhere?

Comment: Your title says limit with L'Hopital, but your tags say limits without L'Hopital's please clarify

Comment: Thank you, I just edited the title

Comment: without l'hopital it is really tough, do you already know what the limit is?

Comment: Yes I know it, the limit is 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(6^{1/n}+4^{1/n}-3^{1/n})^n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(e^{\ln6/n}+e^{\ln4/n}-e^{\ln3/n})^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{\ln6}n\right)^{n/n}+\left(1+\frac{\ln4}n\right)^{n/n}-\left(1+\frac{\ln3}n\right)^{n/n}\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{\ln6}n\right)+\left(1+\frac{\ln4}n\right)-\left(1+\frac{\ln3}n\right)\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln8}n\right)^n\\
&=e^{\ln8}\\
&=8
\end{align}

Comment: How do you swap $$6^{1/n}$$ to $$e^{ln6/n}$$ ?

Comment: @Limitsguy $6=e^{\ln6}$, so $6^{1/n}=(e^{\ln6})^{1/n}=e^{\ln6/n}$.

Comment: +1 Very clever use of the definition of $e^x=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus Really clever, the simplest answer is always the best one

Answer (score 0):

Not allowed you have to take n to infinity at the same time. To solve the limit try using the Sandwich Theorem instead.

Comment: Thank you, how could I use it with this limit? It's the first time I read about it and can't think of a way of using it

Answer (score 0):

$A=\lim_{n\to\infty}6(1+(\dfrac{2}{3})^{1/n}-(\dfrac{1}{2})^{1/n})^n=6e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left[(\dfrac{2}{3})^{1/n}-(\dfrac{1}{2})^{1/n}\right]}$

Now $\dfrac{n(4^{1/n}-3^{1/n})}{6^{1/n}}$ is the quantity whose limit we are interested in.

Consider the function $f(x)=(2/3)^x$ then $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and we have, $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(0)=\log(2/3)$ i.e. $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(2/3)^h-1}{h}=\log(2/3)$.

Similarly consider the function $g(x)=(1/2)^x$ and analogously we have $\log(1/2)=g'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1/2)^h-1}{h}$.

Hence we have the result $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h)-g(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}=\log(2/3)-\log(1/2)=\log(4/3)$

So $\dfrac{n(4^{1/n}-3^{1/n})}{6^{1/n}}=\dfrac{(2/3)^{1/n}-(1/2)^{1/n}}{1/n}\to\log\dfrac{4}{3}$ (here $h=1/n\to0$).

So the final limit is $6e^{\log4/3}=8$.

Comment: Did you for get some logarithms?

Comment: Did I? Please point out, maybe I did mess up :(

Comment: I did not look into details too much, but $n((2/3)^{1/n}-(1/2)^{1/n})\to \log(4/3)$ as $n\to+\infty$...

Comment: I see, maybe my folly was considering $6^{1/n}\to1$ separately. I will check your statement soon.

Comment: you missed a $\log$ in your first line in the exponent...btw, the limit is 8 so $6e^{log4/3}$ looks good

Comment: This looks really good, but I think you messed up somewhere the answer should be $$6e^{log4/3}$$ Also I can't understand the process you make  in the last expression in the second line, could you make it more obvious?

Comment: Then as Mickep said, I computed $\lim_n n((2/3)^{1/n}-(1/2)^{1/n})$ wrong. And in the first line, I used the fact that $\lim_n(1+1/n)^n\to e$ along with some plastic surgery ;)

Comment: Settled everything @Limitsguy

Answer (score 0):

If $L$ is the desired limit then we can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left\{\lim_{n \to \infty}(6^{1/n} + 4^{1/n} - 3^{1/n})^{n}\right\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\log(6^{1/n} + 4^{1/n} - 3^{1/n})^{n}\text{ (via continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\frac{\log(1 + 6^{1/n} + 4^{1/n} - 3^{1/n} - 1)}{6^{1/n} + 4^{1/n} - 3^{1/n} - 1}\cdot(6^{1/n} + 4^{1/n} - 3^{1/n} - 1)\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n(6^{1/n} + 4^{1/n} - 3^{1/n} - 1)\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n(6^{1/n} - 1) + n(4^{1/n} - 1) - n(3^{1/n} - 1)\notag\\
&= \log 6 + \log 4 - \log 3\notag\\
&= \log 8\notag
\end{align}
Hence $L = 8$. We have used the following standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1,\lim_{n \to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1) = \log x$$